# Is there a continuous function from $X$ onto $X$ and from $X$ onto $Y$, given these definitions?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Suppose $X=\{0\}\cup\{1/n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

$$B=\{(n+1)/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

$$Y=X\cup B$$

Is there a continuous function from $Y$ onto $X$?

Is there a continuous function from $X$ onto $Y$?

My attempted for first one is

Yes, $f(x)=x$ for all $ x\in X$  and $$f(x)=1$$  for all  $x\in B$. So, $f$ is onto continuous function

Also, for the Second one my answer there is no onto continuous function between $X$ to $Y$

Is it right?

Comment: The second question doesn't demand onto-ness as currently written - maybe you haven't copied the questions correctly here?

Comment: If you don't require this function to be onto or one-to-one, then you can always take any constant map. Constant functions are continuous, you know.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition that there is no continuous function from $X$ onto $Y$ is correct; it is related to the fact that the points of $Y$ "bunch up" near both 0 and 1, but there are only countably many points in $X$, and these points "bunch up" near a single point.

Suppose $g\colon X\to Y$ were continuous and onto, and suppose that $g(0)\neq 0$.  Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}g(0)$.  Then the continuity of $g$ tells us that there is some $\delta>0$ so that if $|x-0|<\delta$, then
\begin{equation}
|g(x)-g(0)|<\epsilon.
\end{equation}
Because of the way $X$ is defined and our choice of $\epsilon$, we can restate this as: there is some $N\in\mathbf{N}$ so that if $n\geq N$, then
\begin{equation}
|g(1/n)-g(0)|<\frac{1}{2}g(0), \qquad\text{so}\qquad g(1/n)>\frac{1}{2}g(0).
\end{equation}
This means that $1,\frac{1}{2},\ldots,\frac{1}{N-1}$ are the only points of $X$ which $g$ might map into the interval $[0,\frac{1}{2}g(0)]$.  But $Y$ has infinitely many points in this interval, and since $g$ is onto we're asking $g$ to map a finite collection of points onto an infinite collection of points, which is impossible.  So we must have $g(0)=0$.  But you can run through a similar argument to show that $g(0)=1$, so in fact no such $g$ exists.

Do you see how the other half of the argument would work?  We assume that $g(0)\neq 1$ and then use continuity to bound the image of $g$ away from 1.  But onto-ness says that $g$ needs to have infinitely many images near 1, and we get a contradiction.  It's very similar to the $g(0)\neq 0$ case.

Comment: @Gob: You really ought to start upvoting and accepting answers that you find sufficiently helpful.